# Use child routes, but do not render them in a router-outlet

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a code where router config looks like:

```
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddUserComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

By that I'd like to have two pages:

- /users - which shows users list
- /users/add - which shows a form to add a new user

But I don't what to have nested `router-outlet` tags. Both pages I'd like to render in the same, main container which is `app-root`. I know I can do that just by:

```
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'users/add',
    component: AddUserComponent
  }
```

But you probably agree with me that this is not a nice solution and it'd be good to use children construction.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a nested route if you don't have a component assigned to the route => just don't add the component to the definition of the `users` route and make a dedicated empty path for the list page:

```
  {
    path: 'users',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: UsersComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddUserComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

There is a drawback here: if you use a `routerLink` inside of `UsersComponent` where you will use relative path, the empty path will behave still as a path. So you would need to use relative path similar to `../add` and not `./add` as normally one would think

Answer (score 2):

Check this code:

```
{
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: UsersComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        component: AddUserComponent
      }
    ]   
}
```